# Echo a list of all subscriber's user IDs

Tags: users, id

I'm a complete novice with php. Can anyone let me know the code to simply echo/print a complete list of all user IDs on my site who are 'subscribers' (and not to echo any other user data).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users):

```
$subscriber_ids = get_users(
    array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'role'   => 'subscriber',
    )
);

foreach ( $subscriber_ids as $id )
    echo "$id<br />";
```